# How to create internal hyperlinks using DOCX4J from <a href to MS word bookmark/hyperlink. create hyperlink for TOC in word doc using DOCX4J

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a requirement to create hyperlinks for TOC in word document using DOCX4J after converting JSON request to HTML request (

```
String HTMLString = "<div id=\"toc_container\">\r\n" + 
            "<p class=\"toc_title\">Contents</p>\r\n" + 
            "<ul class=\"toc_list\">\r\n" + 
            "  <li><a href=\"#First_Point_Header\">1 First Point Header</a>\r\n" + 
            "  <ul>\r\n" + 
            "    <li><a href=\"#First_Sub_Point_1\">1.1 First Sub Point 1</a></li>\r\n" + 
            "    <li><a href=\"#First_Sub_Point_2\">1.2 First Sub Point 2</a></li>\r\n" + 
            "  </ul>\r\n" + 
            "</li>\r\n" + 
            "<li><a href=\"#Second_Point_Header\">2 Second Point Header</a></li>\r\n" + 
            "<li><a href=\"#Third_Point_Header\">3 Third Point Header</a></li>\r\n" + 
            "</ul>\r\n" + 
            "</div>";
```

I have tried making use of below statements but those methods takes hardcoded value / paragraph values as inputs.
but I need to pass HTML request which is converted from JSON..

```
Hyperlink h = mdp.hyperlinkToBookmark("Target String", "Hit");
mdp.addParagraphOfText("Click here -->  " ).getContent().add(h);
```

Please provide complete code for converting the `<a href>` to MS word hyperlink/bookmarks using DOCX4J which means when I click on TOC(table of contents) heading in word document it should be go to the appropriate page no.

Comment: Please try https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFragment.java then update your question if necessary

Comment: If you just want a TOC, why don't you use a TOC field; see for example https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/TocSample.java

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the reponse.

Comment: I am able to create a TOC and save the word document. can you please help me out by providing code for creating the internal hyperlinks within the same word document for a given HTML content as input. thank u very much in advance.

Comment: Hi @Jason Can you please let me know the code for my requirement..

Comment: You'll need to create a new question explaining in more detail what you are trying to do, but first see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/XHTMLImporterImpl.java#L1813 and https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/BookmarkHelper.java